# No longer getting notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, notifications

Since the website went down for maintenance, I’ve no longer been receiving notifications when someone replies to my posts.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 12.2 (Build 16E227)

Answer (score 10):

Indeed this service was bouncy and unhappy after the move - it's been told where to properly connect to and given a swift kick in the hindquarters. The notification queue should now be flushing. I apologize for what's about to happen to a lot of people's phones...

We don't have as great of a setup on this older push service as we'd like and we're currently deciding between improving that and replacing the service. Some of the things it was built on have been abandoned and due to how device tokens are managed, it's not so easy to just change how things work (e.g. relaying through some service).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just now getting a handful of notifications on my iOS app, from inbox events which were triggered earlier today (and are no longer 'unread'). So I guess there was a stuffed queue somewhere, and it has now been reopened.